# Implementing Autocomplete textbox in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, autocomplete, textbox

I am trying to get an autocomplete textbox working for my website on a web form. This is to autocomplete the textbox with house names once the user has started typing. The sql database is connected and the ado.net model is all set up. I just can't seem to figure out why it is not working.

**The aspx page is below:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $("#<%=txtHouseName%>").autocomplete({
                        source: function (request, response) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetHouseName",
                                data: "{ 'pre':'" + request.term + "'}",
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                        return { value: item }
                                    }))
                                },
                                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert(textStatus);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

  <h3>Auto Complete Textbox without using Web Service</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>House Name: </td>
            <td>
                <div class="ui-widget" style="text-align:left">
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtHouseName" runat="server" Width="350px" CssClass="textboxAuto"  Font-Size="12px" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>        
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**and this is the code behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Houses_of_Mayo
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static List<string> GetHouseName(string pre)
        {
            List<string> allHouseName = new List<string>();
            using (HOMEntities h = new HOMEntities())
            {
                allHouseName = (from a in h.Houses
                                  where a.Name.StartsWith(pre)
                                  select a.Name).ToList();
            }
            return allHouseName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.de/2013/12/autocomplete-textbox-without-webservice.html this should help you. :)

Comment: Does it return anythign?

Comment: Have you looked at the rendered HTML and checked if there's any Javascript errors? Try using the F12 developer tools in Chrome and see if there's anything that helps you.

Comment: @MirkoSbr Thanks, that is the tutorial I have been following but I still haven't managed to get it working.

Comment: @Glitch100 No its not returning anything when it is ran in the browser. I have no errors in my code either so I am very confused.